# Rotate text in horizontal plane

Tags: .net, wpf, storyboard, rendertransform

This will rotate the text like a clock

```
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
    From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:0.2" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
```

How can I rotate the text in the horizontal plane (and see the mirror on the back side) ?
Also I want to rotate about the mid point so the text stays within the TextBlock.
Can this be done with a StoryBoard?

Comment: It appears what I need is PlaneProjection which is available in Silverlight but not WPF.  Odd.

Comment: [WPF Simulating Silverlight's PlaneProjection to Flip Controls](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WPF-Simulating-Silverlights-7ca5b3be) maybe use that as a base example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I've got your requirement correctly,

but is this what your looking for?

[image]

If so you don't need the link in my comment tbh. You could just go with:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="SomeStoryboard"
            AutoReverse="True"
            RepeatBehavior="Forever">
  <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock"
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"
                          Value="-1" />
  </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
...
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
            Text="Some random text">
  <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
      <ScaleTransform />
      <SkewTransform />
      <RotateTransform />
      <TranslateTransform />
    </TransformGroup>
  </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```